# Google map is not working in application using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, intel-xdk

please help me to solve this problem.I am trying to create a mobile app using Angularjs in Intel XDK.The below code is working in XDK.but when I run the live app map is not working.

index.html

```
<div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
                        <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
                        <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
                    </div>
```

App.js

```
$scope.launchGoogleMaps=function(){
        var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude;
      /*  var url = "googlemaps://?center="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude+"&zoom=14";*/
        intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(url);
    }
```

Comment: any errors / warnings in the console?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780521/launchexternal-doesnt-work-on-xdk-app-on-android) ?

Comment: yes I tried this..and its working in Intel XDK.but when I upload this to live application not working there @TanaseButcaru

Comment: same behaviour with ``window.open(url,"_system")`` and cordova inappbrowser plugin installed ?

Comment: In XDK cordova inappbrowser plugin is not available @TanaseButcaru